# How do I access `Images in Pictures folder (Public Directory)` from `webview` in Android Q?

Tags: android, webview, mediastore, android-10.0

I'm migrating a `WebView` Application.
But I couldn't find a way to load `Image in Pictures folder` in Android Q.

I can't use MediaStore in Webview.
what should I do?

Comment: "I can't use MediaStore in Webview" -- you can access `MediaStore` in the programming languages that use `WebView`, such as Java or Kotlin.

Comment: I want to get the image path through js (by add javascript interface) and express that path in <img> tag. How can I use <img src='$someUri'>?